# Recover disk space due to web scraping in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I was using the following Python code for web scraping a news website for the collection of news articles :

```
import mechanize
import re
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2013/07/01/"

link_dictionary = {}
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for tag_li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Op-Ed"}):
    for link in tag_li.findAll('a'):
        link_dictionary[link.string] = link.get('href')
        urlnew = link_dictionary[link.string]
        brnew =  mechanize.Browser()
        htmltextnew = brnew.open(urlnew).read()            
        articletext = ""
        soupnew = BeautifulSoup(htmltextnew)
        for tag in soupnew.findAll('p'):
            articletext += tag.text
        print "opinion " + re.sub('\s+', ' ', articletext, flags=re.M)
driver.close()
```

The above code is for one particular day. When I ran this code for one or two months, it consumed about 3GB of memory space of my `C:\` drive (I am using `Windows7`).

I don't how and why was it consuming so much memory. Can someone explain this phenomenon to me and help also help recover the lost memory? I am new to Python programming.

Comment: Do `driver.quit()`. **P.S.** And if you want your memory back, find selentium (probably) location, and hopefully cache will be somewhere there

Comment: @casanova: if I can ask that you accept advice from experienced members of the community here, I would be most grateful. I edited your question because (a) multiple question marks aren't generally good grammar, and (b) we tend to discourage salutations, advance thanks and signatures here. Think of writing your question like a Wikipedia article. I should be most grateful if you don't revert my edits again (but you are welcome to improve further). Thank you in advance - and glad you are getting the answers you need.

Comment: @Vik2015 Where can I find `selenium` .. I am unable to find it ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @casanova, I think it should be somewhere in your `site-packages` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do some `disk cleanup`. By this you should be able to recover something around 3-4GB. For more recovery, you more recovery of disk space you might have to delete some of your application data.

Answer (score 2):

link_dictionary = {} will continue to grow.

You are never reading from this and don't appear to need it.

Try this:

```
import mechanize
import re
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2013/07/01/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for tag_li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Op-Ed"}):
    for link in tag_li.findAll('a'): 
        urlnew = link.get('href')
        brnew =  mechanize.Browser()
        htmltextnew = brnew.open(urlnew).read()            
        articletext = ""
        soupnew = BeautifulSoup(htmltextnew)
        for tag in soupnew.findAll('p'):
            articletext += tag.text
        print "opinion " + re.sub('\s+', ' ', articletext, flags=re.M)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Sir, I think it is going to work. But can you also suggest me a way to recover the already lost memory ?? I have already lost around 10-12GB of memory.

Comment: Ah sorry I miss understood. One of the libraries must have a cache some where, deleting this should free up your disk space.
Memory is correct but if you edit to disk space in the title, you might get better responses.

Comment: Are you on linux or windows? 
If windows see if there are files in C:\Documents and settings\[user]\Application settings\Temp
if linux have a look in /tmp

Comment: I am on Windows 7 .. let me check

Comment: Sir, I am unable to open`Documents and settings` as `access is denied` prompt is being shown.

Comment: Sir, I ran the program again .. but removal of link_dictionary did not help. Can you suggest something else ?